# Trivia question about snack shipped with computer products

Tags: discussion, scope

I'd like to ask this question but I'm afraid it's off topic as trivia. Is it acceptable?

If it's acceptable but could be improved, please make suggestions.

> I remember that there was a company that packed candy or snacks as a bonus in the shipping box with their products. They were well-known for this practice. I'm pretty sure it was either [Moon Pies](https://moonpie.com/) or [Goo Goo Clusters](https://googoo.com/). I can't remember if the products were hardware or software or if it was a retailer of multiple products.
>
> What company was this, what were the products and when was this done?
>
> I've done some pretty thorough searching and wasn't able to find any mention of this.

Comment: Trivia's off-topic?

Comment: @wizzwizz4: I don't know. That's part of why I'm asking. The other part is it's only peripherally (no pun intended) related to retrocomputing.

Comment: If there's an issue with this question, it would probably be because it's about the _company_ rather than the _computer_. I can't find anyone suggesting trivia's off-topic here; only that it might not make a good question.